# Iterating through database results

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am returning data from my query. Looping through the results and pushing the data in different arrays.
When I try to then loop over the array I am only getting the first set of data and nothing else.

```
 my @data = ();
 for my $row (@$query_data) {
     if($row->[11] == 2)
     {
          push(@data,$row)
     }
 }
```

On the perl script the following works and I am getting expected output.

```
    for my $row (@xm_data) {
       print "$row->[6]\n";
    }
```

outputs

```
   mike
   steve
```

When I do the samething more or less in mojolicious I am getting different results.  I am passing to the render looks `xm_data => @xm_data` and only getting the first results.
The template loops is below.

```
% for my $request_data (@{$xm_data}) {
    <%= $request_data %>
% }
```

if i try the same syntax I do in the `.pl` file I get errors.

Comment: I think we need to see a lot more of your Mojolicious code. Where, for example, does your `xm_data => @xm_data` fit in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about mojolicious, but I do know some perl.

Your `xm_data => @xm_data` looks suspicious to me. If you assign an array to a scalar in perl, it only takes the first element of that array. To assign a pointer to the array, which it looks like you're trying to do, you need to use a backslash.

Eg. `xm_data => \@xm_data`.

That will give you a reference to the array, which then you can dereference later in your `foreach` loop, like it seems you are doing already.

Does that help?

Comment: I will give that a shot tomorrow.  I did have `xm_data => \@xm_data` but I was getting nowhere but it could be because I do not know perl all that well.  Thanks for the information and maybe that was my issue.

Comment: This worked thanks.  For some reason I tried this and it didnt work but maybe I had incorrect syntax.  Thanks.